# How do I get day of the week from a date object?

Tags: ruby

I have a date object in Rails, which I'd like to format.

I've made it this far:

```
delivery_time.date.strftime("%w, %d/%m/%Y")
```

I'd like it to print out 'Wednesday, 04/01/2012'

Is there a quick method to change the '%w' into 'Wednesday'?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Looking at the [Ruby docs for `strftime`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Time.html#method-i-strftime)

```
Time.now.strftime("%A, %d/%m/%Y")
=> "Wednesday, 04/01/2012"
```

The `%A` character is the full day name.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the docs too. I should try remember to check that before I go for random google searches.

Answer (score 15):

```
Date.today.strftime("%A")
=> "Wednesday"

Date.today.strftime("%A").downcase
=> "wednesday"
```

Comment: You can also use `Date::DAYNAMES[Date.today.cwday]`.

Answer (score 7):

I know the OP wanted the string for the weekday, but if for whatever reason you are doing something more algorithmic and need a numerical representation, you can use cwday on the Date object

```
d = Date.new(2017,7,26) 
d.cwday
#=> 3
```

Monday is 1

Comment: For the `Time` Object it would be `wday`. For example `Time.now.wday`

Comment: For both `Date` and `Time`, `wday` returns the weekday in the range 0..6, where 0=Sunday. For `Date`, `cwday` returns the weekday in the range 1..7, where 1=Monday.

Answer (score 4):

`%A` gives you day of the week.

`strftime("%A, %d-%m-%Y")` will give you:

```
Wednesday, 04-01-2012
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use "%A" for the full day name.

See also http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/strftime.html

Answer (score 1):

try `%A` instead of `%w`

```
delivery_time.date.strftime("%A, %d/%m/%Y")
```